# Aurelia eating my Bookmarks

Tags: aurelia

I am working on a legacy application that is being rewritten using Aurelia, the application has a bunch of static html in a tblHelp that needs to be displayed.  I am using innerhtml.bind on a div in my view to databind the stored static HTML into the view.  Each record is essentially a document complete with a full table of contents that links to other divs within the document (Bookmarks).

Something like:

```
<div id="toc">
   <h1>Table of Contents</h1>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a><li>
     <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a><li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="section1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2>
    <p>Paragraph Text...</p>
    <p><a href="#toc">Back to Table of Contents</a></p>
</div>
<div id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
    <p>Paragraph Text...</p>
    <p><a href="#toc">Back to Table of Contents</a></p>
</div>
```

When I display the resulting page in my Aurelia view and click on the links, rather than moving to the proper Div on the current page, it seems to be attempting to route to an unknown route and ends up returning to the home page (that is my unknown route behavior).  How do I make the Aurelia Router know that I am just moving around the same page and do not require it to route to another page?

Comment: I think you need to change your `<div id=` to `<a id=` which is the correct syntax for anchors.  Hopefully Aurelia will recognize them as legitimate anchors.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?  What was it?

Comment: I'm still working on this issue, and found @LStarky's GistRun (linked below) to be informative- however, I believe that the issue may only be relevant when Aurelia is using pushstate navigation, and that GistRun seems to break when setting that option. 

The skeleton navigation apps exhibit the same behavior if you change them to use push state and then add an anchor tag with a hash url. I thought perhaps this was a universal issue with pushstate, but tested on a simple html page, and that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your `<div id=` to `<a id=` which is the correct syntax for anchors.  Hopefully Aurelia will recognize them as legitimate anchors when formatted correctly.

Also, since an anchor tag shouldn't wrap the whole content, you'll just open and close it at the top of the div. You can even leave the divs there but should not duplicate the id.

**Update:**

That being said, I created a [GistRun](https://gist.run/?id=7338a5ab87926f97f86b8f6c5f7494af) that actually demonstrates that Aurelia should be able to handle the `<div id=` anchor targets.  So, I'm not exactly sure why you're having problems.

Maybe this GistRun or the more standard `<a id=` approach will help you.

Comment: I converted all my anchors to the correct syntax; however that did not help with my problem.  For the time being, I disabled my mapUnknownRoutes function and that allows them to work as intended.

Comment: That thought also occurred to me and I actually searched for the "default route" option in Aurelia but didn't find it right away.  It does seem impossible for `mapUnknownRoutes` and local page anchors to co-exist... but it could be done and maybe should be submitted as a bug to the Aurelia development team.

Comment: "The correct syntax" referenced here is not correct in HTML5. What's more, changing to this syntax does not solve this issue in Aurelia. 

I hope that someone can reply here with a way to override Aurelia's router so that anchor tags starting with # are not interpreted as routes. This is going to be a big problem for us since so many of Bootstrap's components rely on this mechanism for inter-page navigation (nav-tabs, scrollspy, etc).

Comment: I believe I've tracked down what is causing this. The tag:

<base href="/">

In the app.html. I believe this is required for correct behavior when using the default hash navigation scheme. But it breaks hash urls when using pushstate. I removed this from my app template, and the app functioned as expected.